# SSL only during login with spring security

Tags: https, spring-security

I'm trying to use https only during login.

The problem is that when the application tries to switch from https to http I end up being redirected to the login form (as if the session is getting destroyed).

Here is the configuration I'm using:

```
<s:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/erro-403"
    create-session="never">

    <s:port-mappings>
        <s:port-mapping http="8080" https="8443" />
    </s:port-mappings>

    <s:intercept-url pattern="/preferencias" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED"
        requires-channel="http" />
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_SIPAS_ADMIN"
        requires-channel="http" />
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/area-prestador/**"
        access="ROLE_SIPAS_PRESTADOR, ROLE_SIPAS_ATENDENTE, ROLE_SIPAS_ADMIN"
        requires-channel="http" />


    <s:intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED"
        requires-channel="https" />

    <s:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/"
        authentication-failure-url="/login-error" always-use-default-target="false" />
    <s:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" />

    <s:remember-me />
</s:http>

<s:authentication-manager>
    <s:authentication-provider user-service-ref="authenticationMBean">
        <s:password-encoder hash="md5" base64="true" />
    </s:authentication-provider>
</s:authentication-manager>
```

The only workaround that I've found is to check the remember-me option.

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Although it's been a long time this question was posted and I am sure the author must have found a solution already, I am posting this answer for future reference.

This issue is discussed in Spring Security [FAQs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-tomcat-https-session). A quick solution is to add this element to your `s:http` element:

```
<s:session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>
```